# programa que lee solo un número del 0-9

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando hacer una función que pida un numero del 0 al 9 al usuario y que sea robusta. He estado mirando códigos para guiarme y la mayoría fallan al encontrarse con alguna de estas situaciones, normalmente debido al uso de cin:
1- Si el usuario introduce espacios antes del numero o después, la entrada es válida
2- Si se pulsa control+z (eof en windows) se produce un ciclo infinito
3- Si el usuario tipeo 2ff la entrada resulta válida
4- La entrada se queda esperando a que tecleemos algo por culpa de algún salto de línea
He hecho el siguiente código, creo que soluciona los problemas comentados anteriormente. Me gustaría saber su opinión y si creen en algún caso dónde podría fallar o si puedo mejorarlo. Creo que el código es lo suficientemente pequeño y comprensible como para publicarlo aquí.

```
int pedir_numero()
{

    string data = "";
    while (true)
    {

        cout << "Introduce una opcion: ";
        if (!getline(cin, data))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (data.length() != 1 || isspace(data[0]))
        {
            cerr << "Numero invalido, vuelve a intentarlo!" << endl;
            continue;
        }
        try
        {
            return stoi(data);
        }
        catch (const exception &e)
        {
            cerr << "Numero invalido, vuelve a intentarlo!" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Si el usuario introduce espacios antes del numero o después, la entrada es válida

Una opción es leer toda la línea del tirón y, posteriormente, evaluar si el contenido es exclusivamente numérico.

```
int numero;
std::string linea;
std::getline(std::cin, linea);
bool ok = std::all_of(std::begin(linea), std::end(linea),
                      [](char c) { return std::isdigit(c); });
```

Una vez que sabemos que la secuencia completa es numérica, nos falta saber si puede ser convertido a un entero:

```
if( ok )
{
  try
  {
    numero = stoi(linea);
  }

  catch(std::exception const& error)
  {
    ok = false;
  }
}
```

Al final del proceso, si `ok` es `true`, en `numero` tendremos el número final.

> Si se pulsa control+z (eof en windows) se produce un ciclo infinito

Hay una forma de descartar caracteres del buffer de entrada, y es mediante la función `cin.ignore()`. El problema que tenemos aquí es que dicha función **es bloqueante**. Esto quiere decir que si la ejecutas cuando en el buffer de entrada solo hay un caracter EOF, el programa se bloqueará hasta que la función `ignore` tenga algo que pueda descartar... y no es lo que quieres.

Los programas actuales no suelen funcionar bajo consola precisamente por la cantidad de limitaciones que presenta esta interfaz.

> Si el usuario tipeo 2ff la entrada resulta válida

El código del primer caso trata esa entrada como no válida

> La entrada se queda esperando a que tecleemos algo por culpa de algún salto de línea

Ahí poco puedes hacer. La entrada estándar, tanto de C como de C++, no es interactiva, sino que solo reacciona ante los saltos de línea.

Para conseguir un comportamiento diferente tendrías que hablar directamente con el Sistema Operativo y, en ese caso, la respuesta concreta a tu pregunta dependerá del Sistema Operativo utilizado.

Puedes ver un ejemplo **completo** funcionando [aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/O0N3GOSWp853B4EB)

Comment: gracias por compartir una altenativa, sin embargo falla en los puntos 2,3 y 4. Si se introduce ctrl+z dato vale cero ,si se introduce 2ff dato vale 2 y si se ponen espacios antes o despues de introducir un numero dato vale ese número aún habiendo espacios

Comment: te olvidaste el ; en el último false

Comment: No se si me he explicado bien pero el código que puse como ejemplo intenta evitar estas situaciones, aceptando solamente números. No puede haber espacios, ni letras ni cualquier cosa que no sea un número

Comment: @theriver el código del primer punto invalida `2ff`, ya que `f` no es un dígito. El código final es una composición de los dos puntos... por eso reutilizo `ok`. Lo del `CTRL+Z` y el `;` ya te dije que estoy escribiendo desde el móvil

Comment: el codigo que puse invalida 2ff pero el tuyo no

Comment: @theriver no me suele gustar que me traten de mentiroso. [Aqui](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ihpb27eVQJTLsKVF) puedes ver como `ok` es `false` ante la entrada `2ff`.

Comment: disculpas, ahora te entiendo, no me pare a mirar el codigo y estaba usando un cout para mostrar el valor de retorno de tu codigo, mea culpa

Comment: Todo en una función creo que quedaría así: [código](https://ideone.com/4HAoer)

Comment: @theriver no tienes que disculparte. Ha sido simplemente un malentendido. Un saludo